# Class Structure in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a class Person i.e. the definition of Person with name and age.  SuperClass is main Class. I want to display name and age in a textBox on Flash document.

I am newbie to Flash. Something wrong in the class structure or coding conventions. It gives error "Call to possibly undefined method addChild".

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class SuperbClass extends Sprite{
        public function SuperbClass() {
        var p1=new Person("Brinda",30); 

        }
    }   
}
import flash.text.TextField;
 class Person {  
     private var name:String;
     private var age:Number;
     var tf:TextField;      
     public function Person(n:String,a:Number){
         name=n;
         age=a;
         init();
     }
     public function init():void{
         trace(name+' is '+age+' year old');    
         tf=new TextField();
         tf.text=name+' is '+age+' year old';
         addChild(tf);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Person Class is a data object and should not be trying to perform View operations.

So:

```
protected var p1:Person;
protected var tf:Textfield;

public function SuperbClass() {
   p1 = new Person('Brenda', 30);
   tf = new TextField();
   tf.text = p1.name + ' is ' + p1.age + ' years old.';
   addChild(tf);//SuperBClass extends Sprite, so this works
}
```

Note that you will need to make the Person variables public for the above code to work.  Alternatively, you can create a getter on Person that returns the entire string:

```
public function get info():String {
   return name + ' is ' + age +  ' years old.';
}
```

You'd call this like:

```
tf.text = p1.info;
```

Comment: If I add another getter public function get name:String{ return name;} . Why it doesn't work ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but if your private variable has the same name as the getter function, it won't work.  This is why many people choose to prepend "_" to their private variable names as a matter of convention (for example _name).

Answer (score 0):

Your person class needs to extend Movieclip or Sprite or something that has the addChild method.